# Remove first character from Ruby string using [1..n]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to basically trying to remove the `.` in the the string `.extension`

So I'm using

```
'.extension'[1..10] #gives extension
```

Of course this will work for 10 characters, how would I make it work for any length. I dont know what to search for because I dont know what this array style `[x..y]` is called.

Comment: [READ. THE. DOCS.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: im sorry I didnt know where to look I thought this would come under arrays

Comment: @Akshat: [It's there too](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice).

Comment: @Akshat: Understood. So you know, every object in Ruby has its own methods, depending on class. Any class can implement a `[]` method, or a `===` method, or a `+` method. Look at the class of the object you are calling the method on and you will find the methods available. Since `'extension'` is a String, look at [its methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use negative indexes. This will offset them from the end. -1 is the last element, -2 is the second last and so on.

```
'.extension'[1..-1] # => extension
```